# template SFINAE and enable_if to switch between dynamic and fixed size

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am new to SFINAE. I have a template that I would like to be able to accept classes that the size could be determined simply calling sizeof(x) or in case the value is dynamic it will require x.size().

I am trying to wrap my head around how as smooth as possible this could looks like and I think interface: `size_t size(const Item& item)` seems to be good enough.

The following is an example that works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Fixed {
public:
    typedef T Item;

    static const bool kFixedSize = true;

    static size_t size() {
        return sizeof(T);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Dynamic {
public:
    typedef T Item;

    static const bool kFixedSize = false;

    static size_t size(const T& item) {
        return item.size();
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Serialize {
public:
    template <typename = typename std::enable_if<T::kFixedSize> >
    size_t size(typename T::Item&) {
        return T::size();
    }

    template <typename = typename std::enable_if<!T::kFixedSize> >
    size_t size(const typename T::Item& item) {
        return T::size(item);
    }
};


int main() {
    Serialize< Fixed<int> > fixed;
    int a = 0;
    std::cout << fixed.size(a) << std::endl;

    Serialize< Dynamic<std::string> > dynamic;
    std::cout << dynamic.size("string") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It has an issues though one is: `size_t size(typename T::Item&)` and the other is `size_t size(const typename T::Item& item)` else the compiler compliance that I am overloading the template. The second is it seems like too match very tricky code to achieve the goal - is there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this

```
//class hierarchy to set the priority for type matching
struct second_priority
{
};
struct first_priority : public second_priority
{};

template<typename T>
auto size_impl(T const & data, second_priority t) -> int
{
    return sizeof(data);
}

template<typename T>
auto size_impl(T const & data , first_priority t) -> decltype(data.size(),int())
{
   return data.size();
}

template<typename T>
int size(T const & data )
{
    return size_impl(data,first_priority{});    
}
```

Comment: `_second` in a global namespace is a reserved identifier

Comment: *any* identifier in a global namespace that begins with an underscore is reserved

Answer (score 0):

I think @Gautam Jha presented a nice solution using SFINAE. You can shorten it a bit by using ellipsis for the 'else' case, so you don't need to use this auxiliary class and it's inheritance:

```
template<typename T>
auto size_impl(T const & item, int) -> decltype(item.size())
{
  return item.size();
}


template<typename T>
auto size_impl(T const & item, ...) -> size_t
{
  return sizeof(T);
}

template<typename T>
auto size(T const & item) -> size_t
{
  return size_impl(item, 0);
}
```

It's cool that you're playing around with SFINAE, but usually there are simpler (i.e. to read and to understand) ways to achieve the same, see the solution of POW (which has unfortunately been deleted).

Answer (score 0):

Since all you want to do is call different functions to get the size in `Dynamic` or `Fixed`, you can just implement these classes differently and use them in Serialize:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Fixed {
public:
    typedef T Item;

    static size_t size(const T&) {
        return sizeof(T);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Dynamic {
public:
    typedef T Item;

    static size_t size(const T& item) {
        return item.size();
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Serialize {
public:
   size_t size(typename T::Item const& x) {
        return T::size(x);
    }
};


int main() {
    Serialize< Fixed<int> > fixed;
    int a = 0;
    std::cout << fixed.size(a) << std::endl;

    Serialize< Dynamic<std::string> > dynamic;
    std::cout << dynamic.size( std::string{"string"} ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, I would consider using a type-trait or a free function to do the same. This would be more extensible, because you have to just provide a new trait or an overload for new types, e.g. some container which has only a length method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#include <type_traits>

size_t size(int) {return sizeof(int);}
size_t size(std::string const& s) {return s.size();}

template<typename T>
struct size_trait
{

};

template<>
struct size_trait<int>
{
    static size_t size(int) {return sizeof(int);}
};

template<>
struct size_trait<std::string>
{
    static size_t size(std::string const& x) {return x.size();}
};

template <typename T>
class Serialize {
public:
   size_t size(T const& x) {
        return ::size(x);
    }

    size_t size_(T const& x) {
        return size_trait<T>::size(x);
    }
};


int main() {
    Serialize< int > fixed;
    int a = 0;
    std::cout << fixed.size(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fixed.size_(a) << std::endl;

    Serialize< std::string > dynamic;
    std::cout << dynamic.size( std::string{"string"} ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << dynamic.size_( std::string{"string"} ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```